# Is it possible to recover cells with hidden content wiped out upon opening with LibreOffice

Tags: data-recovery, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Some of my `.xls` Microsoft Excel files contain cells with hidden information formatted using custom code `;;;` to deter casual viewing. I made the switch to LibreOffice a year ago and converted all the files to `.ods` format. Except for lost formatting, I wasn't aware of any hidden dangers. A year later, to my horror, I discovered that some of cells with such hidden formatting have their content cleared out. I note that the custom format code was changed to `[>0]"";[<0]"";"";""`.

To prove that this indeed happen, I did a test on a new `.ods` file and sure enough, some of the hidden cells have their content cleared upon saving and reopening the file. As an example:

- Cells containing pure Latin characters, e.g. `abcdefg` remain visible
- Cells containing a mixture of letters and numbers, e.g. `abc123` got
  **deleted**
- Cells containing pure numbers, e.g. `123456` stays hidden.

Is there a way to recover the deleted content? I am not sure if it is really deleted or just not showing on the spreadsheet input line.

Comment: What happens if you reference such a cell in a formula like =A1 ?? If this returns 0 then the cell is empty.

Comment: @teylyn, looks like it is gone forever...

Comment: I cannot understand how Libre Office would remove cell contents based on cell formatting. This just does not make sense. Like if the cell is formatted with RED font, remove, otherwise keep. Same for: if the cell is formatted with "nothing for positive; nothing for negative; nothing for zeroes; nothing for text" -- which in Excel convention is the custom format ";;;"  - remove cell content, otherwise keep? -- I have plenty of Excel versions installed on several computers and virtual machines. So I can confirm that in Excel, these formats are not a problem. You may need to take it up with Libre.

Comment: @teylyn, did you convert to `.ods` for the test. I am no longer a Windows user, so have to rely on whatever free office product that comes with the OS. So you are not a LibreOffice user?

Comment: No, I'm not a Libre Office user. If your problem relates to Libre Office only, please remove the Excel tags, since Excel rules no longer apply to whatever you're doing. As I said above: take it out with Libre.